# Creating shortcut with a simple command in CMD.exe

Tags: cmd, exe

I need a code for `cmd.exe` for creating a shortcut on any user's desktop.

Comment: There isn't straightforward way to do that

Comment: Below link might be useful for you -

http://superuser.com/questions/455364/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-a-batch-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application will be in the same folder on all machines (like `C:\Program Files\Software\Start.exe`) then create a shortcut, place it on a network drive, or in the .cmd file's folder, and simply just copy it to `C:\%username%\Desktop`